# Why doesn't views::split work in both places when apparent value is the same

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

I'm working with the ranges library in C++23 with the Advent of Code. This is from Day 3.

Why does split work in the first place I've marked but not the second? Either will probably be okay for my code but I'd like to understand more.

My question is why view algorithms seem to work in some places but not others. I know from the error message it is because the ranges on the lhs & rhs of the | operator are different. But why? Shouldn't a range algo work with any range? What changes when *proc_triple* lambda is called by the *fold_left* without the *split* in the argument that changes the range.

Interestingly, putting a views:drop in place of the error vws::split works.

Update: removed the use of vws::all in the pipeline that doesn't work. Left it in by mistake. Code doesn't work with it removed.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <iomanip>

namespace rng = std::ranges;
namespace vws = std::views;

auto execute = [ ](std::string_view aoc_data) noexcept -> uint64_t {
   using vws::split, rng::fold_left;
   using std::string_view, std::quoted;

   auto summation =
      [ ](uint64_t const sum, auto&& aoc_triple) noexcept -> uint64_t {

         auto
            proc_triple = [ ](uint64_t sum, auto&& lines) noexcept -> uint64_t {
            for (auto line: lines | split('\n')) {
// ========= why does it work here ====^^^^
             std::cout << quoted(string_view {lines}) << "\n";
            }
            return 0;
         };

         auto res = fold_left(aoc_triple | split('\n'), 0, proc_triple);
//             ========== error here ====^
//   ========== why won't split work here ====^^^^
         std::cout << '\n';
         return sum;
      };

   return rng::fold_left(
      aoc_data | vws::split('\n') | vws::slide(3) | vws::take(3), 0ul,
      summation);
};
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main() {
   std::string_view test_data1 { //
      R"(467..114..
...*......
..35..633.
)" //
   };
   execute(test_data1);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? From your example, I really can't see what you want to do with the original `string_view`.

Comment: At this point, I want to know why I can't use the vws::split at the line where the error occurs. This is a learning project pushing my understanding of the ranges library using the Advent of Code problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:

```
std::string_view test_data1 {
    R"(467..114..
...*......
..35..633.
)"
   };
```

`test_data1 | vws::split('\n')` basically gives you a range of size **4** with elements `string_view` (technically it is `subrange<const char*, const char*>`, but it can be simply regarded as `string_view`):

```
["467..114..", "...*......", "..35..633.", ""]
```

By analogy, `test_data1 | vws::split('\n') | vws::slide(3)` will give you a range of size **2**, and its element is also a range, which consists of 3 `string_views`:

```
[
 ["467..114..", "...*......", "..35..633."], 
 ["...*......", "..35..633.", ""]
]
```

This means that in `rng::fold_left(test_data1 | vws::split('\n') | vws::slide(3), 0, summation)`, the second argument of `summation`, namely `aoc_triple`, is actually a range containing 3 `string_view`s.

So it cannot be split by `'\n'`, only its elements, `string_view`, can be split by `'\n'`, even though they no longer contain `'\n'`, as I showed at the beginning.